# Nativescript listview select/deselect show/hide checkbox

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want select and deselect in Nativescript Vue List View and than show and hide checkbox of the item selected.

Comment: What did you tried, or where are you stuck? We can't help if we don't see any code.

Comment: Define two templates one with checkbox and another without checkbox, choose the right template [with if](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/#using-listview-with-multiple-v-template-blocks), when you like to show checkbox toggle the conditional statement. You may also use one template and operate on the visibility of checkbox based on the conditional statement.